# Is it somehow possible to get transaction details from any paypal user using my service?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

Assume the following situation: 
I have a 3rd party service offering some kind of analytics/report/whatever... on a paypal user's transaction history.
Is it possible to fetch payments (only amount - in case that matters) of private paypal accounts (ofc assuming they somehow granted access by registering to my service), even though they didn't buy anything of me directly?

I hope the situation is somewhat clear, unfortunately I coulnd't find any matching questions on the web.

Thanks in advande!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to [download activity](https://www.paypal.com/reports/dlog) and import a CSV than to query transactions via API, but there is a [Transaction Search API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/transaction-search/) that can be used.

Comment: But how should I be able to download an export of foreign users? I asked if/how I can fetch payments from other users.
The API sounds interesting and I also took a look into it already, still i don't know how to fetch other user's payment information.

Comment: You can't download it, they can. You can import the CSV.  For the API, they have to give you access. Use their first party credentials, or try to integrate marketplace partner onboarding to obtain third party permission (this is more complicated)

Comment: Oh ok - that's what you meant, I see. That's not an option unfortunately...
But could you maybe explain or link an example considering the API? I already tried some things with it in sanbox but I felt like it's only supposed to fetch transactions to/from my business account directly... So is there a way for users to easily grant access to my app? Thanks a lot!